# Is the reputation algorithm used published anywhere?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If yes, can you please provide a link and also add it in the list of FAQs? Any ways this question is tagged with faq. How does it compare with other reputation algorithms? If no, why not? Even if you are in the process of submitting for a patent (for an algorithm?), one can publish it while it is being processed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this link tells you exactly how much reputation you get or lose depending on other user's actions on your answers and questions, and your actions that affect your reputation:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

It is not patented, nor is anyone seeking a patent.

Comment: Thank you, I must be dumb or lazy in not checking the FAQ first. May be the 'Related Questions Extractor' (the one that kicks in when a person starts writing the description of question) should also check the FAQ list! I am not sure if in this particular case, it would have found the match or not, but it also be considered, I think.

Comment: Everyone uses different words for their titles.  Now that this one is in the system, it will show up if someone poses a similar question in the future.